# How to display streaming images in OpenCV?

Tags: c, opencv, edsdk

I'd like to implement the live view function using EDSDK. I have used EdsGetPointer to get the pointer of the memory address for memory streaming. Now I want to display the streaming image on the PC.

I have read in some people use the API on VisualC such as ATL or CImage which able display the streaming image just by passing the pointer of the memory stream as the parameter, and the function could retrieve the streaming images by itself. I am thinking of using OpenCV in order to display the streaming images as I don't have VisualC installed on my computer. Is there any function on OpenCV that I can use to display streaming images? Or is there any other alternatives  that I can use to deal with streaming images from EDSDK?

Answer (score 3):

You can pack the data into an `IplImage` and show it using `cvShowImage` in a loop: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html  The down side is you're tied into the OpenCV event loop.

There are alternatives.  In the past I've used OpenGL to paint an image as a texture so that I could manage the viewport, draw on top of it, etc.  You can get a simple and flexible working GUI pretty quickly using GLUT.  A benefit to that is that whatever OpenGL code you write will be portable to any other UI library you use as long as that library has an OpenGL canvas widget.  What I always do is Camera->IplImage->OpenGL Texture->wxWidgets glCanvas.  I still use OpenCV for the actual image processing, etc.  It's totally cross-platform and doesn't require the pay version of VC++.

Comment: The image display functions in openCV are really only mean to be "just good enough" to look at the results of your image processing, you wouldn't use them for something like a video player.

Answer (score 1):

are you want it for LiveView ? if not for liveview, you can save your streaming image in host 
using

```
Error = EdsCreateFileStream(dirItemInfo.szFileName, EDSDK.EdsFileCreateDisposition.CreateAlways, EDSDK.EdsAccess.ReadWrite, out stream);
```

then you can load it

```
IplImage *inImg = cvLoadImage("photo2.jpg");
```

and then can process the image in opencv.